# Can I track 2 sub-domains with same Google Analytics code for mobiles (i.e. ga.php)

Tags: google-analytics

Let say I have first.mydomain.com and second.mydomain.com, what if I install same GA code to each of those different domains. Is this possible? if so how Google Analytics will show these both for a single profile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible to use the same tracking code on multiple sites.  And GA will essentially aggregate all the data together.

Now the good thing is that Google Analytics has a **hostname** dimension which you could use to differentiate the traffic between your two subdomains.   You could use filters on the hostname if you are using the Custom Report utility or the Google Analytics API to get the data yourself.